# Как выбрать одно из значений с определенной вероятностью?

Tags: python, алгоритм, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Пример. Катя получила 10 баллов, а Коля — 20 баллов.
Значит в одном случае из трех победит Катя, а в двух из трех — Коля.

Надо случайным образом выбрать победителя лотереи, учитывая их вероятности на выигрыш.

Какой формулой это расчитывается (Нужна универсальная формула для любого числа участников лотереи)?

P.S. Язык Python.

Comment: Если рандомное число от 0 до 30, больше 10 то победит Коля, если нет то Катя. В чем возникла сложность?

Comment: Господа, а за что собственно минусуете? Хороший вопрос (только формулировка немного подкачала)

Comment: Самого интересует, как это сотворить.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Примем за условие:

> Игрок 1 - вероятность выигрыша 10
>   Игрок 2 - вероятность выигрыша 20

В простом случае, нам надо сложить все вероятности выигрыша вместе (то есть 10 + 20 в примере) и потом сгенерировать случайное число в диапазон от 0 до суммы вероятностей (до 30). Далее, от получившегося случайного числа, отнимать вероятности выигрыша по очереди (например, идем сверху вниз), и как только разность станет меньше 0 - вы нашли искомого Игрока (победителя).

Итак, пример:

```
10 + 20 = 30 // сумма вероятностей
Random(30) = 26.67 // случайное число
26.67 - 10 = 16.67 // вычитаем вероятность 1 игрока
16.67 - 20 = -3.33 // вычитаем вероятность 2 игрока
// Результат стал меньше 0. Значит 2-й игрок - искомый победитель
```

---

В английской среде алгоритм имеет название ["Roulette wheel selection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) (и часто используется в генетических алгоритмах). Такое название дано в связи с тем, что можно представить все вероятности как сектора рулеточного колеса (на рисунке они приведены к процентам от суммы), и случайным образом выбирать положение на колесе, определяя тем самым "выигравший" сектор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятно. Если выпало 7.46, то кто победил? И почему?

Comment: Если выпало 7.46, то мы отнимаем 10 и сразу же получаем отрицательное число, значит выиграл первый.

Comment: Почему 10, а не 20? Да и в вашем примере почему начинаем с 10, а не с 20?

Comment: @Эникейщик отредактировал ответ. Мы начинаем вычитания по очереди. На самом деле порядок очереди не важен (можем и снизу-вверх идти), главное чтобы он сохранялся при последующих вызовах.

Comment: Самое смешное, что последействия нигде нет, поэтому порядок при каждом вызове может быть любым. При условии, что вы не выбираете порядок на основе выпавшего случайного числа =)

Comment: @AmaroVita вы правы

Comment: @MarinaaaniraM если веса равны, то это никакого значения не имеет и алгоритм никак не меняет.

Answer (score 14):

В Питоне уже есть готовая функция, чтобы выбрать победителя в соответствии с весами:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choices(['Катя', 'Коля'], weights=[10, 20])
['Коля']  # пример возможного вывода
```

Можно проверить, что Kоля выбирается в ~2/3 случаев, а Катя в ~1/3 в среднем:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(random.choices(['Катя', 'Коля'], weights=[10, 20])[0]
...         for _ in range(100000))
Counter({'Коля': 66715, 'Катя': 33285})
```

Для случая, только двух участников, легко самостоятельно реализовать выбор:

```
>>> 'Катя' if random.random() < 1/3 else 'Коля'
'Коля'
```

Похожие результаты:

```
>>> Counter('Катя' if random.random() < 1/3 else 'Коля'
...         for _ in range(100000))
Counter({'Коля': 66617, 'Катя': 33383})
```

Чтобы сложнее было победителя предсказать, можно `secrets` модуль использовать:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> 'Катя' if secrets.randbelow(30) < 10 else 'Коля'
'Коля'
```

`randbelow()` может вернуть 30 возможных значений `[0, 30)`, при этом для 10 выпавших значений `[0, 10)` выбирается Катя (1/3 vs. 2/3 разделение).

В общем случае, могут быть отличия, сколько случайных бит генерируется и по какому алгоритму  в приведённых примерах. В разных ситуациях, разный выбор может быть более подходящим.