# Как задать определённый процент выпадения в python

Tags: python, кодировка, функциональное-программирование

Сколь бы я не гуглил не мог найти ответ на этот вопрос...

Задача:
  Сделать так что - бы например дробовик выпадал с 30% шансом, а пистолет с 80% шансом. И да... 100% процентов тут не причём например, позже я - бы смог изменить процент выпадения дробовика на  45%

Язык: Python

Comment: Если речь об **одном** событии (выпадает или пистолет, или дробовик), то с точки зрения математики вопрос бессмысленен, потому что в сумме не может быть 110%

Comment: Изучите модуль `random`

Comment: Но если отказаться от процентов и взять просто абстрактные веса 30 и 80, то читайте [Как выбрать одно из значений с определенной вероятностью?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798057/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e)

Comment: random.randint(1, 100), потом отсеивайте все числа больше 30, вот вам и 30%, т. е. засчитывайте все числа, которые в диапазоне от 1 до 30, они-то и будут выпадать с вероятностью 30%