# Python. Случайность с вероятностью

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Бьюсь уже третий день, никак не могу победить. Хочется сгенерировать ряд случайных чисел в цикле например в диапазоне от 0 до 100, но при этом наибольшая кучность была бы в районе 30, а шансы на генерацию например 100 или 0 были минимальны, но возможны. Я в Пайтон только только осваиваю азы, прошу сильно не пинать.
Вот что насоображал, но это конечно не то, что предполагалось.

```
value = int(r(10, 30))

if value >= 15:
    value += int(r(0, 35))
    value = int(value / 2)
if value >= 20:
    value += int(r(20, 40))
    value = int(value / 2)
if value >= 30:
    value += int(r(20, 45))
    value = int(value / 2)
if value >= 39:
    value = int(r(35, 100))
value = int(value)
return value
```

[image: Примерное распределение вероятности]

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798057/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E

Comment: [Распределение Пуассона](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 3):

Для произвольной (не аналитической) кривой: дискретизуйте ваш график

1. Мысленно разбейте плоскость вашего графика на квадратики размера 1. По горизонтали вы получите 100 шагов. Каждому целочисленному значению координаты `x` в диапазоне `[0, 100]` соответствует целочисленное (округленное) значение вашего графика `y = H(x)`.
2. Составим целочисленный массив `F[101]` по следующему закону

   F[i] = Σ<sub>k=0...i</sub> H(k)

   Элемент `F[i]` будет содержать суммарную дискретную площадь под графиком слева от вертикали `x = i`. Этот массив будет неубывающим.

   Элемент `F[101]` - вся дискретная площадь под графиком в диапазоне `[0, 100]`.

   (Как несложно догадаться, массив `F` - это дискретизованное ненормализованное табличное задание функции распределения вашей вероятности.)
3. Генерируем случайное число `r` в диапазоне `[0, F[101])` и любым методом ищем такое значение `i`, что `r` попадает в диапазон `[F[i], F[i+1])`.
4. Это значение `i` - и есть ваша случайная величина.

При желании, аналогичным образом вы можете разработать схему более "грубой" дискретизации графика - с более широким шагом. Или адаптивную дискретизацию, которая уменьшает шаг на негоризонтальных участках графика и идет широким шагом на горизонтальных (ваш код как раз выглядит, как неудавшаяся попытка сделать именно это).

Comment: Я бы с гаусианом поигрался, даже написал ответ, но сделать правое плечо шире - надо подумать...

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, подойдет простая модель с использованием `random.choices` и весов?

```
import random
import collections

res = random.choices(
    population=[[0,10], [10,30], [30, 40], [40,50], [50,60], [60,70], [70,80], [80,100]],
    weights=[0.05, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.025],
    k=100)

res = sorted(collections.Counter(map(str,res)).items())
```

Выверку весов я не делал - просто по-быстрому для наглядности накидал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интерпретатор отвечает, что нет атрибута choises в random. Есть choise, но тогда выходит ошибка TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'population'... Куда копать?

Comment: choice и choices - разные методы. какая версия pyhton у вас? Если меньше 3.6, то тогда воспользуйтесь модулем numpy: `from numpy.random import choice` (здесь как раз choice, а не choices) - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html