# Вероятность события, используя проценты

Tags: java, веб-программирование, события

Допустим у меня есть кнопка и 5 событий.

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялось одно из событий с определенным шансом: обычное 70%, редкое 20%, эпическое 10%, легендарное 1% и мистическое 0.05%

Как это реализовать? И куда закидывать скрипт

Comment: "это реализовать я вобще нечего не понимаю" - значит Вам еще рано браться за такие сложные задачи

Comment: определитесь с язком программирования

Comment: Одно из событий при нажатии на кнопку, вот только, нажатие на кнопку-  это тоже событие.

Comment: Например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798077/177188

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выбрать одно из значений с определенной вероятностью?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798057/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e)

Comment: Сумма вероятностей `70% + 20% + 10% + 1% + 0.05%` составляет 101.05%.

Answer (score 4):

1. Создаём enum, в котором прописываем названия событий и их допустимые вероятности

```java
public enum ProbableEvent {
    REGULAR(70),
    RARE(20),
    EPIC(10),
    LEGENDARY(1),
    MYSTICAL(0.05);
    
    private final double probability;

    private ProbableEvent(double percent) {
        this.probability = percent;
    }
    
    public double getProbability() {
        return this.probability;
    }
}
```

2. Также пишем статический метод для расчёта суммарной вероятности, чтобы можно было корректно рассчитать частоту генерации событий, кэшируем расчёт суммы.

```java
    private static double total = -1;
    private static double total() {
        if (total < 0) {
            total = Arrays.stream(ProbableEvent.values())
                .mapToDouble(ProbableEvent::getProbability)
                .sum();
        }
        return total;
    }
```

3. Пишем статический метод, возвращающий рандомное событие с заданной приведенной вероятностью (например 70% / 1.01005 = 69.3035%, и т.д.)

```java
    private static final Random RANDOM = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public static ProbableEvent getRandom() {
        int range = (int)(total() * 100);
        double x = RANDOM.nextInt(range) / 100.0;
        double limit = 0.0;
        for (ProbableEvent pe : ProbableEvent.values()) {
            limit += pe.probability;
            if (x < limit) {
                return pe;
            }
        }
        return ProbableEvent.MYSTICAL;
    }
```

Тест: вызываем метод `ProbableEvent::getRandom` 100_000 раз, строим и выводим карту частот:

```java
int runs = 100_000;

Map<ProbableEvent, Integer> freq = Stream
    .generate(ProbableEvent::getRandom)
    .limit(runs)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> x,
        Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)
    ));
freq.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<ProbableEvent, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
    .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%-10s count = %6d %% = %6.3f%n", 
        e.getKey().name(), e.getValue(), 100.0 * e.getValue() / runs
    ));
```

Вывод:

```
REGULAR    count =  69082 % = 69.082
RARE       count =  19829 % = 19.829
EPIC       count =  10053 % = 10.053
LEGENDARY  count =    994 % =  0.994
MYSTICAL   count =     42 % =  0.042
```

Comment: Наредкость обстоятельный ответ на не самый хорошо сформулированный вопрос! Бинго!