# Указать вероятность в python

Tags: python

Есть воин, а так же метод attack, в котором воин с вероятностью 1/3 нанесет 5 урона, с вероятностью 1/3 нанесет 7 урона, и с вероятностью 1/3 не нанесет урона вовсе. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выбрать одно из значений с определенной вероятностью?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798057/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в таком примитивном виде (когда вероятности равны) так:

```
import random

damages = [0, 5, 7]
damage = random.choice(damages)
```