# Генерация целых чисел с шансом

Tags: java, алгоритм

я задался вопросом: как сделать рандомайзер в java целых чисел, но с шансом. То есть есть диапазон от 0 до 100 и цифры целые. Но хотелось бы сделать так, что бы шанс выпадения какого-то числа был 20% или другой шанс

Comment: Если диапазон чисел небольшой, то можно просто накидать массив, где 20% массива будет занято вашим числом. И выбирайте случайный элемент массива.

Comment: [Как выбрать одно из значений с определенной вероятностью?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/798057)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообразим массив (Отсортированный), где: `number` - числа, а `chance` - их количество в массиве

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        int[] number = new int[] {0, 1,  23, 456, 7890, 12345}; // Числа
        int[] chance = new int[] {0, 50, 1, 1,    1,    10   }; // Количество

        int count = IntStream.of(chance).sum(); // Считаем количество элементов воображаемого массива

        // Вывод вероятностей:
        for (int i = 0; i < chance.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Вероятность числа \"" + number[i] + "\":  \t" + (chance[i]*100d/count) + "%");
        }
        
        // Генерация случайного числа
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int randomNumsCount = 0; randomNumsCount < 10; randomNumsCount++) {
            
            int index = random.nextInt(count); // Выбираем случайный индекс из воображаемого массива

            for (int i = 0; i < chance.length; i++) { // Ищем элемент, которому принадлежит этот индекс
                index -= chance[i];
                if(index < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Случайное число: " + number[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

##### Примеры массивов:

###### `Число 10` - 50%

###### `Число 100` - 50%

```
int[] number = new int[] {10, 100};
int[] chance = new int[] {50, 50};  // или new int[] {1, 1} или new int[] {25, 25}
```

###### Воображаемый массив: `{10, 25}`

---

###### `Число 15` - 20%

###### `Число 20` - 30%

###### `Число 25` - 50%

```
int[] number = new int[] {15, 20, 25};
int[] chance = new int[] {2,  3,  5};  // или new int[] {20, 30, 50} ...
```

###### Воображаемый массив: `{15,15, 20,20,20, 25,25,25,25,25}`

---

Comment: `new Random()` надо выволочь из цикла. А если вынести массивы, во а втором использовать шанс того, что число <= указанного, а не ==, то можно будет применить бинпоиск и улучшить асимптотику.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, что про `Random` напомнили, а то совсем забыл про него :)

Comment: @Agzam, на ваш взгляд, чем алгоритм лучше, чем мой, предложеннный тут сначала? Мой покороче выглядит (не настаиваю, что он лучше:-).  Тем, что решает задачу обобщённо или для конкретного применения,как в вопросе он тоже больше нравится?

Comment: Человеческое спасибо! Огромное

Comment: @Сергей, редко бывает надо только для одного числа задать вероятность. Этот алгоритм более универсальный.

Comment: Я вариант с бинпоиском сделал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ясно, спасибо. Так и думал. Я подхожу к вопросам более утилитарно - что Заказхчик хочет, то и получает. Обощённые методы часто менее эффективные (за счет гораздо лучшей масштабируемости).

Answer (score 3):

Генерация каждого числа работает за логарифм от их количества: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZZI9c4MwDIZ3foVGuASf3Y@JZGi3rs3IMTjEIaZggm3S5HL8dio@TJJmkH2W9Mh6dcr5iYf57qfrZHmstIUcHaSxsiAfWvOLibynwDdXu6qMPC8tuDHwKRXXl43gOj0wuHoAx2ZbyBSM5RYvqSxkQgnNrfBHFvRwLftYnIBqyq3Qxj3TA1epMMFQCwb@DOuJIUqc7Zey/pQVTzcphMrsIWRJEM2YRGyUQbZ3XTp2CWeXvAdfwgpoMDAhgxDkGNLCNlq5HmOZ9O4W7UnoqZI7KLlU/sZqqTKUwnU263iQjp8o8Tv5/FvLt2lMGaPvSpcADI8XtFeKxxvaO0WovWcnYY9szzBnWGd@UGQHeF9p1I8Dq9csgnr1ONMIFovaqQD3R1wnsFjfXjj5sZP2qSbtazJK/xXaXIwVJakaS444L1sof94TtyDzarilCNwnvbVd9wc)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

class BinarySearch1 {
  public static int generate(Random random, int[] numbers, int[] chances) {
    int x = random.nextInt(chances[chances.length-1]);
    int i = Arrays.binarySearch(chances, x);
    if (i < 0) i = -1 - i;
    return numbers[i];
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] numbers = new int[] {0,  10, 20, 300, 40, 50   };
    int[] chances = new int[] {20, 10, 10, 1,   10, 10, 0};

    for (int q=1; q<chances.length; ++q) {
      chances[q] += chances[q-1];
    }

    for (int q=0; q<100; ++q) {
      System.out.println(generate(random, numbers, chances));
    }
  }
}
```

Вероятности выпадения:

- p(0) = 20/(20+10+10+1+10+10) = 20/51
- p(10) = p(20) = p(40) = p(50) = 10/51
- p(300) = 1/51

Нельзя использовать нулевые шансы.

Answer (score 2):

На псевдокоде, так как не пишу на java (тут 21% по факту, если надо ровно 20%, то при первой генерации надо диапазон взять от 0 до 0,95 - даст 19% и 1% даст вторая генерация):

```
ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ (случайного целого Числа1 в диапазоне от 0 до 5):
ЕСЛИ Число1 = 0 
   Результат=Желаемое_Число
ИНАЧЕ ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ (случайного целого Числа2 в диапазоне от 0 до 100) 
   Результат = Число2
```

Comment: Немного неправильно. Вместо 20% получается 21%, т. к. желаемое число попадает во второй диапазон.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, но я же об этом и писал в тексте над кодом за 6 часов до вашего комментария:-), когда 0,95 предлагал в качестве границы первого интервала, если 20% важно.

Comment: Кажется, я не прочитал)